# Проблема в обращении к базе данных на MySql

Tags: mysql

Как обратится к базе данным `MySql`? У меня установлен сервер `xampp`.

Comment: из PHP или Perl? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

для PHP:

```
/* Переменные для соединения с базой данных */ 
    $hostname = "имя хоста"; 
    $username = "имя юзера"; 
    $password = "ну тут ясно"; 
    $dbName = "имя базы";
```

---

```
//так для локалки
$db = mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $dbName) OR DIE ("<font color='ff0000'><b>Error! Не могу создать соединение!</b></font>");
//так для инета
$db = mysql_connect ($hostname, $username, $password) OR DIE ("<font color='#ff0000'>Error! Не могу создать соединение с базой</font>");
```

Comment: а как узнать username pasword?

Comment: "а как узнать username pasword?" - базу разве не вы создавали?
Тогда узнать можно у того, кто её делал.